# How do you convert a structured reference in excel to a range?

Tags: excel

I have a table with columns that have headers. I'd like to be able to convert the structured reference `[Column 2]` to the range `B1:B1000` and `Table1[[#Data],[Column2]]` to the range `B2:B1000`.

edit for context:

This is in the formula editor so the structured references refer to a table in the current worksheet.

Comment: Are you wanting this in Formulas or VBA?

Comment: Some context?  How are you getting the structured reference?

Comment: The Structured ref comes from a table in the formula editor, but VBA is fine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will give you the address:

```
Activesheet.Range("Table1[[#Data],[Column2]]").Address()
```

This would give you a reference to the range itself

```
Dim rng As Range
Set rng = Activesheet.Range("Table1[[#Data],[Column2]]")
```

Answer (score 1):

In the Table options you can select the option *Convert to Range* which will change structured references in formulas to range references, you can then choose Insert Table to reinstate the table. To simplify formulas you could use find & replace e.g. `Sheet1!` and `$` with blank.