# How to convert dynamic (structured) reference in Excel to fixed cell value?

Tags: excel, structured-references

I am loading a table into an excel file from a separate file - from this import table I would like to create "sub-tables" defined just by specific columns. Therefore I am using dynamic referencing to see only parts of these tables on a different sheets, what I would like to do in one step is to fix the values from the structured reference at their individual cells. Is there a solution to that, or is it better to use a completely different approach?

Sample table with the table SAMPLE - I would like to fix the values of the references in the columns G,H and J,K,L respectively and convert them into two tabels

[image: Sample table]

One of the solution is with the macro which copies and pastes as a number the reference, but it is not very nice and the automation of the procedure is not very smooth. i also tried this solution [How do you convert a structured reference in excel to a range?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12134663/how-do-you-convert-a-structured-reference-in-excel-to-a-range) but it does not work for me

Edit: Based on @Ike response I am attaching current VBA code which is copying and pasting specified range to a new worksheet where I can then create a table out of it. But I would like to do that but without the copy-paste process...

```
    Sub Macro1()
    Range("Sample_range").Copy
    Set NewBook = Worksheets.Add
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks_     :=False, Transpose:=False 
    End Sub
```

Comment: You definitly need VBA for that - or you have to do it manually: copy the result range (G1: H10) - paste as value and then turn into table. Maybe you should post your VBA - and tell us what is not "very nice"

Comment: The code I am trying to implement is sort of like this:

`Sub Macro1()
    Range("Sample_range").Copy
    Set NewBook = Worksheets.Add
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub` 

This is basically copying the range and pasting to another worksheet - I can workaround with that, but I cannot figure out whether there is a way to just simply create new table without this copy - paste process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is indeed not very nice.

Try this one

```vb
Sub convertSpilledRangeToTable(c As Range)

If c.HasSpill Then
    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = c.cells(1,1).SpillParent.SpillingToRange
    
    rg.Value = rg.Value   'this turns the formula into values
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = rg.Parent
    ws.ListObjects.Add xlSrcRange, rg, , xlYes
End If

End Sub
```

You can test it e.g. like this `convertSpilledRangeToTable  Range("Sample_range")` where I assume "Sample_Range" to be G1 from the screenshot.

Or - if you already create the sub-tables via code - include it there.

Comment: Oh yeah, this is much better code, but I have slight issue with it - the HasSpill method actually is not True for the range - if I debug it, then it skips the If statement. I cannot figure out why it is not True for the range...

Comment: hard to judge without seeing your data and code. Maybe select `G1` and then run `convertSpilledRangeToTable  selection` in the debug window

Comment: Yes, with specification of the cell it works! Now I can work from that up, thank you!